# How does Tor defend against Sybil attacks?

Tags: security, attacks

Sybil attacks target the weaknesses in the reputation system. How does Tor deal with such attacks? Recently, the Lizard Squad tried to take control of the Tor network by creating a large number of nodes, but the attack failed. However, is Tor vulnerable to more sophisticated forms of Sybil attacks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lizard Squad was a pretty noisy sybil. We have monitoring for events of that sort...

https://gitweb.torproject.org/doctor.git/tree/sybil_checker.py

Naturally that event has sparked interest in more sophisticated sybil detection...

https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-dev/2015-January/008156.html
  https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-dev/2015-January/008095.html

If you're interested in helping we'd love to have you. This is an area that could certainly use more development attention.

Comment: I am interested in helping. Perhaps pattern recognition in Relay names and addresses is the next step (used in conjunction with fingerprint check). If you have already something, I'am all ears.

Comment: Great! Please subscribe to tor-dev@ and ask there (https://lists.torproject.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/tor-dev). Philipp Winter has given the most thought to sybil detection but no doubt he would love to have some help!